# SQLConnect() failed to connect server

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, connection

I am trying to use SQLConnect() to connect sqlserver with C++:

```
 retcode = SQLConnect(hdbc, (UCHAR*)"My server name", 
           strlen((const char*)"My server name"),(UCHAR*)"My ID", 
           strlen((const char*)"My ID"),(UCHAR*)"My PW", 
           strlen((const char*)"My PW"));
```

but it always `return -1 to "retcode"`. Is there anything wrong with the format of my server name? And how could I set the initial catalog of it?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of SQLConnect is as below

```
SQLRETURN SQLConnect(
     SQLHDBC        ConnectionHandle,
     SQLCHAR *      ServerName,
     SQLSMALLINT    NameLength1,
     SQLCHAR *      UserName,
     SQLSMALLINT    NameLength2,
     SQLCHAR *      Authentication,
     SQLSMALLINT    NameLength3);
```

eg:

```
 retcode=   SQLConnect(hdbc, (SQLCHAR*) "servername", SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*) NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
```

change the example according to your requirement and check

More information [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711810(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: So how about the user name and password?

Comment: So how could I set the initial catalog?

Comment: just try and check the result